# Constructing a small set of numbers whose differences cover $\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb N$.

Given a set $S\subset\mathbb N$, let $\Delta(S) = \{a-b\mid a,b\in S\}$ denote its set of differences.

I'm interested in finding a small set $S_n$ such that $\{1,\ldots,n\}\subseteq\Delta(S_n)$.

For example, if $n=8$ we can use

$$S_8 =\{1,2,4,8,9\}.
$$

> **How can we construct a small $S_n$ efficiently? (Efficiently should ideally be $O(|S_n|)$ time, but any $o(n)$ time would be interesting.)**

> **How does the smallest $|S_n|$ grow as a function of $n$?** (As a guess, I'd like to say $|S_n|=O(\sqrt n)$ should be possible?)

Answer (score 4):

One example of such a set is $S_n = \{0,1,2,\dots,k\} \cup \{k,2k,3k,\dots,k^2\}$ where $k=\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$.  It follows that $|S_n|=O(\sqrt{n})$, and $S_n$ can be constructed in $O(\sqrt{n})$ time.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168079/14578.

Comment: This seems to give an easy 2-approx for $|S_n|$. Any thoughts on whether this can be improved?

Comment: @MA, If you want to know how small $|S_n|$ can be, that sounds like a good question for Math.SE.  I'm not sure that it is a matter of computer science.

Comment: Isn't finding an optimal solution (or a $c$-approx. for $c<2$) a matter of computer science? I asked here because I am interested in something I can program, I'm not sure that Math.SE. is the right place for that.

Comment: @MA, yes, you are right.  If it were me, I would ask first on Math.SE, as many constructions are easily implementable and difference sets are well studied in mathematics, but it is up to you.  In any case, this is a new question and should be asked separately.